# AngularJS - php mailer keeps returning "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, phpmailer

The app.js controller which handles contact form looks as follows:

```
app.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.result = 'hidden'
$scope.resultMessage;
$scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
$scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
$scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
$scope.submit = function(contactform) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
    if (contactform.$valid) {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'contact-form.php',
            data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result='bg-success';
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result='bg-danger';
            }
        });
    } else {
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed :( Please fill out all the fields.';
        $scope.result='bg-danger';
    }
}
});
```

Unfortunately, it keeps returning the "500 (Internal Server Error)". It seems that file "contact-form.php" is unable to be found. I suppose it's something with the path which cannot be detected properly.I double checked and the "contact-form.php" is in main directory, so I guess it's something with angular paths.

But maybe the issue lays elsewhere. Perhaps it's worth to paste the contact-form.php code as well.

```
         <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) &&        isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {

//check if any of the inputs are empty
if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

//create an instance of PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
$mail->AddAddress('test@gmail.com'); //recipient 
$mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
$mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);

if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
    $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
}

if(!$mail->send()) {
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

$data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
echo json_encode($data);

} else {

$data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error 500 is a server error, check your php server for logs

Comment: Turn PHP error on in your PHP.ini or through `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` in your code.

Comment: where exactly should I paste this line?

Comment: On top, are you able to access the ini file?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't see any ini file. So paste in contact-form.php?

Comment: if on linux, try: tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log